# mediaplayer start() on button click issue

Tags: android, arrays, random, media-player

I have created an array of sounds that is randomly accessed to play via MediaPlayer when a button is pressed - this works fine my only issue is that when testing it and pressing the button rapidly the sound would stop and not play anymore - is there some way I can implement a start stop thing? I tried beginning my onClick method with a butPress.stop() but my android emulator didn't like it. the code follows :

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {


try{
    display.setText(pp.getText());
    int x = r.nextInt(sfx.length);
    butPress = MediaPlayer.create(PitchMaker.this, sfx[x]);
    butPress.start();
}catch(Exception e){
    display.setText("Whoops we had a problem. Please try again");
}
```

}

Comment: If you're having errors, be specific. Saying your emu 'doesn't like it' is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this line of code in the catch block so that we can get the exact error report.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: no error code is being generated ..the problem only seems to occur when rapidly pressing the button which activates the sound ..so there might be no way to stop it ..maybe it just overloads the mediaplayer ?

Comment: Declare Boolean playing = false; Then public void onClick(View arg0) {
try{
    display.setText(pp.getText());
    int x = r.nextInt(sfx.length);if(playing) { butPress.stop();} else{
    butPress = MediaPlayer.create(PitchMaker.this, sfx[x]);}
    butPress.start();
}catch(Exception e){
    display.setText("Whoops we had a problem. Please try again");
}
}